# How to convert DateTime object to string in Crystal Reports

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports

I have a simple line of Crystal Reports code below:

```
EffectiveDateTimeString = ToText({Command.EffectiveDate} , "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" );
```

However, when I try to validate the formula, I get a error saying "Too many arguments have been given to this function" with "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" selected. Command.EffectiveDate is the DateTime object. How can I convert this to a string?

Thanks!

Comment: Is {Command.EffectiveDate} in DateTime format or Date format?

Comment: It's a C# DateTime object. I tested just displaying {Command.EffectiveDate} and saw something in the format of "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm"

Comment: See my answer below, I think all it is is the format of the DateTime. You need to use "/" instead of "-" for the Date portion.

Comment: I've switched to using "/" but I still get the same error message with both lines:

Comment: Then either something is wrong with your {Command.EffectiveDate} or some other code interferes. You said "...saw something in the format of "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm"". Can you post what exactly the value is? Is there any other code besides your snippet that could interfere? Can you post more of the code?

Comment: OK, I'm an idiot. EffectiveDate is actually a string. Sorry guys. Lesson learned!

Comment: Well, that'll do it. No way any of the code samples given in the answers wouldn't have worked on a DateTime field.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the assignment operator `:=`, not the equivalency one `=`:

```
EffectiveDateTimeString := ToText({Command.EffectiveDate} , "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" );
```

**edit **

This snippet works as expected:

```
ToText(CurrentDate + CurrentTime, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

Ensure that your field is actually returning a date/time, rather than one or the other.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I totally forgot about that. But I tried that and I still got the message, "Too many arguments have been given to this function"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
EffectiveDateTimeString := CStr(DateTime({Command.EffectiveDate} , "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" ));
```

If {Command.EffectiveDate} is not in the right format, this will ensure that it is indeed DateTime.

If that doesn't work, I just created a simple formula in a sample report of mine, and the below code worked just fine on a DateTime field:

```
stringVar EffectiveDateTimeString;
EffectiveDateTimeString := CStr({Command.EffectiveDate}, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
EffectiveDateTimeString
```